# Largest Contentful paint(LCP) and Total blocking Time (TBT) and Cumulative layout shift (CLS) not displayed in the Lighthouse report

Tags: puppeteer, lighthouse

I was running lighthouse through puppeteer and I have generated the report successfully but when I took a look at the metrics displayed in the report  I couldn't find the Larget Contentful paint(LCP) and Total blocking Time (TBT) and Cumulative layout shift (CLS) instead the report generated with other values like First CPU Idle and First Meaningful Paint and Max Potential First Input Delay

I don't know why the metrics are different I tried to run it through the browser I got the normal metrics but I don't know why the puppeteer script generated different ones

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkyHa.png)